# How can I show the contact number of the Dialed contact

Tags: iphone

I want the contact number to appear on the dialling screen when initiating call that if contact has more than one number I want to know which number I had dialled.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you cannot display the number of a contact while calling him. However, there's a way of identifying the number you are calling by adding a custom Contact Label.

To do so:

1. Open Contacts app
2. Search for you desired contact
3. Tap Edit in the top right corner to edit your contact
4. Tap the label next to the number on the left. (see image below)
5. Choose a label for that number (see image below)
6. Do the same for the other numbers

Then, when you call that contact, the label will appear directly below the contact's name.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @MahmoudMohammed could you please upvote my answer and mark it as the correct answer if you think it deserves it? Thanks!

Comment: Ok but can you guide me how to up-vote it

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work